# Is it possible to write any action without any result in struts2 config file

Tags: java, struts2, action

Is it possible to write any action without any result in struts2 config file ? like

```
 < action name="showResult" class="com.mmi.webInterface.ShowResultAction"/>
```

but in stuts1.x it is possible to write any action without any forward result. like

```
< action path="/JsonResponse" type="com.mmi.webInterface.JsonResponseAction"
  validate="false"/>
```

my question is that how can i write any action without any result in struts 2 config file?
because i have to use Ajax on the same page so no need of any result in action.

Comment: without defining result you can't write any action class according Struts2 architecture. Does you ajax doesn't need any response from action class.

Comment: thanks @MohanaRaoSV  yaa my ajax need response from action class. all response from action is a ajax responsetext which i have to show in the same page.

Comment: @neerajbharti: i do not see a reason of not specifying result in your config as in S2 results have 2 distinct meanings,first it provides a logical name and Second, the result element provides a result type.Even in your Ajax case your execute method needs to tell if it executed successful or any other issue.In All the request flow work like this and i do not see any benefits of not specifying the result, even `<result>mytest.jsp</result>` will do work for you.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi when i use result in config as s2 then the response of ajax contains the jsp file content not my action class response. i have to show my action class response on the same page.

Comment: @neerajbharti: are you sending back JSON data back to UI? In that case i need to tell S2 that my result will be JSON data and without which i do not see a way to handle this.In short be it a AJAX call or any other normal call, we need to tell that to which view the response should bind.that's said this is the way request-response is working under the hood

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yaaa i m sending back JSON data back to UI

Comment: but how to tell s2 config that my data is a JSON data and how to bind response

Comment: @neerajbharti: S2 comes with a JSON plugin which will convert the data to JSON from your action class and will send data back as JSON format to your action class.http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html

Comment: thanks @UmeshAwasthi i am working on it if i face problem i will disturn u again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write it like :

```
<action name="ActionName" class="ClassName" method="methodName" />
```

We are using such actions in our application, where there is no need to display a page as a result. It works fine.

Comment: thanks @Umer hayet but it shows an error action without any result

Comment: yaaa it shows an error " Could not find action or result  No result defined for action com.mmi.webInterface.ShowResultAction and result success "

Comment: @neerajbharti It is not showing any error and working fine here. I am using struts 2.2.3.

Comment: but in my case it shows an error .......i dont know y it shows an error? i m also using struts 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Specify dummy locations. For example,

```
<action name="showResult" class="com.mmi.webInterface.ShowResultAction">
    <result name="success">dummy</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

<action name="actionName" class="ClassName" method="methodName">
</action>

The method methodName should be of type void else you'd get an error saying that no result is defined for this action.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an action without specifying a result.

```
<action name="showResult" class="com.mmi.webInterface.ShowResultAction" />
```

Then, make your action return null and the result will be ignored.

```
class ShowResultAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Override
    public String execute() {
    
       // some code
    
       return null;
    }   
}
```